# How to protect pre populated readonly database to being copied by someone who will use android app

Tags: android

I have pre populated SQLite database which I will only read from android app no write or update is required. how can I protect my database to be copied by someone who will use my app.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't. Anything on the phone can be accessed by anyone who wants to spend the time to get it. For example, rooted device users can simply copy the database from your app's portion of internal storage.

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt the database with a password and decrypt it at runtime.

Comment: Yes, but anyone else can decrypt it too, since the encryption key and the encryption algorithm are part of your app.

Answer (score 0):

RULE OF THUMB: If there is a method to make it, there will always be a method to break it.

But You can always do it with standard procedure and safeguard it is much as possible.  To start with-

Use SQLLite encryption 
https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

An add on would be to have two keys to your locked database - one which the user inserts using Auth and the other would be to make a server side call before accessing the database which you will insert.

And since in Computer Science, there are trade offs, like make an internet call before access, unable to access offline. There are methods to do so, but again, its space, time, memory, UX, security and all factors. So this answer is just the tip of tip of the iceberg